# XCode project updated from a folder on HDD

Tags: xcode, project, directory

I need a way to make Xcode aware of changes in a folder (and all its subfolders) and add the new files in the project automatically.

The folder (and all its subfolders) will contain code files.

Now, i know i could just make a build script and run that script when compiling but i need the files to be visible in Xcode also. 
Is there a quick, easy way, or at least a way, to make Xcode updates it's content with files from a folder?

Thanks

Comment: It seams the answer was right in from of me. When you select to add new files to the project. Select a folder then in the open dialogue window select "Create folder references for any added folders" and then press "Add".Now Xcode will see any changes you do to that folder  (and all its content) and update accordingly.